# Can not read xml data into flash

Tags: xml, flash

I write a simple xml code, and I try to read the xml file into flash, but I got "undefined" in my output.
The codes are as following. Do you know how to sove the problem? Thanks.

xml file (test.xml):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
<note>
 <to>Tom</to>
 <from>Peter</from>
 <heading>Reminder</heading>
 <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Flash program:

```
xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("test.xml");
x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("to")[0];
t1.text=x.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

Sincerely,
John

Comment: try typing four spaces before your xml code, that should allow the XML to be posted.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the contents of your XML file is just this one line?

```
Tom Peter Reminder Don't forget me this weekend!
```

If so, that could be your problem right there. Or if your tags are missing in the questions, that because you need to tell StackOverflow to format it as code by selecting it and pressing the code button (or `Ctrl + K`). Please edit your question, otherwise I cannot tell whether there is a problem with the statement you have used to parse the XML.

*Another problem* I see is in your ActionsScript:
You may not load the XML file and then parse it immediately after, because it doesn't happen sequentially (happens in a different thread). You need to use a `URLLoader`  to load the XML, and add an event listener for the `URLLoader`'s `Event.COMPLETE` event. In that method, do what you need to do with parsing the XML.

---

I am assuming you are using AS3 and not AS2

#### EDIT : Added code sample

In the main method where you start loading from the XML

```
var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, showNote);
```

Create a new method

```
function showNote(e:Event):void
{    
    var note:XML = new XML(e.target.data);
    var to:String = note.to[0].text();
    var from:String = note.from[0].text();
    var body:String = note.body[0].text();
    //t1.text = "To: " + to + "\nFrom: " + from + "\n\n" + body;
    t1.htmlText = "<p>To: " + to + "</p><p>From: " + from + "</p><p>" + body + "</p>";
}
```

Be sure to make sure that you have declared a text field on the stage with the instance name of `t1`, and to set its properties to multiline with wrap for this to work.

So basically, I think the problem with your original code was one of the following:

1. You wanted a String, and to get that from and XML node, you need to use the `text()` method. There are other ways as well, but this is themost basic.
2. The way you are traversing the XML tree using `getElementsByTagName` and `childNodes` may or may not be correct, but it is certainly easier to get wrong. AS3 provides a much more intuitive means to *get* the stuff from the XML, such as the one I have given in my example.